# How to create a superuser in Content Hub

Tags: content-hub

I would like to create a superuser whose credentials will be used in the CMP connection string.

I see this error while trying to create a superuser.  I tried `all` & `any` in the `Policy combination` section.

> The operation causes a violation of a unique constraint on at least
> one of the properties: for property define by..

[image]

Not sure of the version, but the Sitecore Connector for Content Hub being used in v4.0

**UPDATE:**

I was trying to create a user with name `sitecorecmpsyncuser`.
I tried `sitecorecmpuser` and it worked.

Comment: Did you follow this to create user? https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/connect-for-ch/51/connect-for-content-hub/create-a-user-in-sitecore-content-hub.html

Comment: @SumitBhatia I don't know which version it is. But the Connector we are using in v4.0. I have updated my question.

Comment: check if it is OOTB user

Answer (score 2):

To create user we followed below steps -

1. Go to Admin Panel and select `Users`
2. Click on `Add User` button
3. In the Details tab, provide the `Username` and `Modules`
4. In the `User groups` section - Click on `Add to user group` in the left hand side and select `Superusers` from popup.
5. Then in the `Policy combination` We selected `any` policy and select `Add item`, that's it, it will add superuser.
6. Save.

[image]

Comment: Can you please check my question. I have tried the same

Answer (score 2):

Try using these steps and connection string values that will help you in setup and configuration.

1. Create a Sitecore CMP User (Ex: SitecoreCMPUser) in Sitecore Content Hub (Go to Sitecore Content Hub Instance >> Manage >> User). Under User Groups add group memberships for Everyone and Superusers.

   Edit Profile, add valid email and Reset password to receive an email to set a new password.

   Note: On adding membership, you may get a Policy combination error but don’t bother, just save the User Profile. Membership will be added automatically.
2. Make a note of the LogicApp’s Client id and ClientSecret settings (Manage >> OAuth Clients >> LogicApp )
3. Create a Sitecore Content Hub action. Use the out-of-the-box M Azure Service Bus on a Content Hub instance option.

   Got to Sitecore Content Hub Instance >> Manage >> Actions (Create Action)
   Set the following values  :  • Name: Sitecore • Type: M Azure Service Bus • Label: Sitecore.
   Copy the Hub in and Hub out string values. You will need these to configure the Sitecore connection string.

To establish the connection refer to this thread.

https://community.sitecore.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=b15745a31b814110b8954371b24bcb09

Comment: I'm failing at Step 1. Pls see the snap in question

Comment: AS per the answer given in thread "On adding membership, you may get a Policy combination error but don’t bother, just save the User Profile. Membership will be added automatically" So is it happing on your solution?